# Getting SQL Server up to run phpunit in bitbucket-pipelines

Tags: sql-server, laravel, bitbucket-pipelines

I need to place phpunit tests into the pipeline. They almost all use the SQL Server database. Right now when the pipeline is run I get lots of:

```
1) Tests\Unit\OrganisationControllerTest::testExample
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver
```

so I need a way to install SQL Server first, then call the usual migration and seeds or just run an SQL dump to populate it. Here's what part of my `bitbucket.piplelines.yml` looks like. Any examples of how this ought to be put together to accomplish the goal?

```
    unittest:
      - step:
          name: New Unit Tests
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - mv "env/.env-unit" ".env"
            - mv -f "public/azure.web.config" "public/web.config"
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install
            - vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php
            - zip -r unit_deployment.zip .
          services:
            - sqlserver
          artifacts:
            - unit_deployment.zip

definitions:
  services:
    sqlserver:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
      variables:
        ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        SA_PASSWORD: YourStrong!Passw0rd
```